# Making home server available from internet

Tags: networking, router, wan

I'm trying to configure router to make my home server available from internet.
I would like to have 2 services(ssh and web-server) visible from *outside*. They are available from *inside* as:

```
192.168.1.X port 22
192.168.1.X port 80
```

but not by external WAN IP. I made 2 entries in *NAT -- Virtual Servers Setup* in my router configurations, for ports 22 and 80, to my home server IP (192.168.1.X) but it didn't help.

The server has static routing set. Does anyone has any idea what did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does your router come with a firewall of some kind? I have seen some that block traffic on those ports.

Comment: Your ISP could be blocking you.

Comment: As this depends on tour router's model and on your ISP's policy, you should ask them. They will be able to help you doing this.